# Quickblox chat idea

Tags: chat, quickblox

In a chat group. Can I restrict access to some users to upload? For example, in a group chat of classroom only the teacher has the ability to upload and students can download and chat only. Any help on this will be much appreciated. I'm using android studio for my app.

Answer (score 0):

It's all a matter of knowing if the current user is a teacher or student. You can check this after a successful login and save whether the current user is a teacher or student using SharedPreferences. Then you hide the button that allows for uploading of files if the current user is a student. It's not really a complex matter that you need quickblox solving. Hope this was helpful.